# Content disappears after refreshing of page (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a plugin where i have a form and a submit button. The form-action is `the_permalink()`. When the user clicks on the submit-button, a message `("hello")` should be visible, which works fine with this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   display();
}
function display()
{
    echo "hello";
}
```

But if i refresh the page, the message is gone. Does anybody know how to fix this to that the message stays there?

This has porbably something to do with that i compare `$_POST` with `'submit'`, which is not given after a refresh...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would think youre right.  youre only calling your display function if `$_POST['submit']` isset.. if you refresh the page and clear the post headers then that will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following code

```
   session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   $display_val = display();
   $_SESSION['display_val'] = $display_val;
}

if(isset($_SESSION['display_val']))
{
    echo $_SESSION['display_val'];
}


function display()
{
    return "hello";
}
```